# How to get a key value from a LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, kotlin, key-value, linkedhashmap

I am trying to retrieve a LinkedHashMap key value, but I do not find any coherent solution for my problem, I am using firebase power to download the content for the LinkedHashMap but I do not any solution for retrieving the Question key value of the LinkedHashMap named d

I have this code:

```
linkedHashMapForLessonContent = (intent.getSerializableExtra(tags?.LESSON_MAP_TAG_NAME) as WrapperSerializer<LinkedHashMap<String, Any>>).get() as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>
```

Which returns a LinkedHashMap with the keys:
`{0={...}, 1={...}, 2={...}, 3={...}, 4={...}...}`
Then I try to get the `"0"` value this way

```
var d = (linkedHashMapForLessonContent as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>)["0"]
Log.e("d", d.toString())
```

which returns

```
{Question=What is Gravity?, Content=[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/someimage0, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/someimage1, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/someimage2, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/someimage3], Type=Images, Answer=0}
```

So I want to return the value of the Question as the following

```
Log.e("hello world", something to get the question value)
```

That will return

```
'What is Gravity?'
```

I have tried multiple solutions and searched multiple things but no thing has the answer for my problem, I would be thankful if someone helps me out with this :)
Thank you

Comment: There is a joke about getting the question in there somewhere. In Java I'd try `(String) d.get("Question")` I suppose?

Comment: So you recommend me to pass the code to java?

Comment: No, but I presume you can do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: yeah I actually tried that in kotlin which translates to d["Question"] but it seems like the d LinkedHashMap is not set as a HashMap but as an any value so I am like no way

Comment: LinkedHashMap implements the Map interface, which means it has a get() method, which means you can use square brackets just fine with it, as any other Map in Kotlin.  If you're having an error with that please be specific about how it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I don't understand your chain of casts in the first line of code.  What the heck is going on in there?  Can you simplify that without casting so much?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `var d = linkedHashMapForLessonContent["0"] as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>`?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I get an error so I changed it to: ```var d = (linkedHashMapForLessonContent as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>)["0"]``` which returns a ```any``` value so it is not useful at all to get the ```Question``` key value

Comment: What error were you getting? Because if you cast it before retrieval of the value, then of course you get `Any`. I think you have to backtrack some... Now if you cast to `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Any>>` in your current then that might work, but I would expect you'd get the same error you encountered initially\.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, so pretty much I have a class that Serializes a ```LinkedHashMap``` when I pass it as an Intent Extra because when you pass it you are going to get a HashMap so it messes up the order and then the class I have called ```Wrapper Serializer``` 'maintains' it as a ```LinkedHashMap``` to not lose the order, I just put it so that you know where the ```d``` is coming from that you help me to set it as a ```LinkedHashMap``` and not as a ```any``` value as it is returned in the code I have

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica yeah so I cast it as ```var d: LinkedHashMap<String, Any> = (linkedHashMapForLessonContent as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>)["0"] as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>``` but I get an error

Comment: error: ```Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sense/com.example.sense.CourseContentActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `d.toString()` to a JSON then get "question" value:

```
JSONObject(d.toString())["question"].toString()
```

Comment: someone that actually does what a question is for: answering, thank you!